# How to proxy a re-written url in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

I have the following config:

```
js_include /etc/nginx/scripts/encode_request.js;
js_set $encoded_request re_encode_url;
log_format logEncoded $encoded_request;

server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       listen [::]:443;

       server_name myfirst-domain.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;

       location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                if ($request_uri ~ ^/lool/https%3A/alf.mydomain.com/(.*)$){
                     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log logEncoded; #Output the encoded url to the logs. (For debugging purposes)
                     rewrite ^/lool/https%3A/alf.mydomain.com/(.*)$ $encoded_request;
                }
                proxy_pass              https://localhost:9980;

        }
}
```

The purpose of which is to filter a URL request that that contains a decoded URL that's required by the backend service. The problem is whilst the request URL has been successfully encoded, it is not being proxied to the backend service and instead I get the original decoded URL which in turn causes an error, though I do get the correctly encoded URL output in the access.log.
Not by far an NGINX or web server saavy person so I'd appreciate some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong / missing.
Another thing that might be of note is that the request upgrades to websocket communication between the client and the sever and I am proxying that.
I'm using NGINX 1.13.6 on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using [nginScript](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs_about.html) in the end.
I tossed the conditional and just did everything in nginScript, so the virtual host file (or server block) is simplified thus:

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443;

   server_name myfirst-domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /path/to/ssl/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key     /path/to/ssl/certificate/key;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

            #Optional
            access_log /var/log/nginx/ll_access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/ll_error.log;

            proxy_pass    https://127.0.0.1:9980$encoded_request;
    }
```

}